# Classe Mail do PHP não carrega as variáveis na View

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

O Laravel fica me retornando como variável não definida, para a variável $bloger.
Já tentei de todas as formas que conheço, mas persiste o erro.
Já fiz o carregamento da view através da controller e funcionou perfeitamente, o problema é realmente nesta classe.
Laravel 5.5

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Newsletter extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $request, $blog;

    public function __construct($request, $blog)
    {
        $this->blog = $blog;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        info($this->blog);
        info($this->request);

        $params = ['bloger'=>'blogar'];

        return $this->view('email.newsletter')->with(['bloger'=>'blog']);
        // return $this->view('email.newsletter')->with($params);
        // return $this->view('email.newsletter', ['bloger'=>'blog']);
        // return $this->view('email.newsletter', $params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aparentemente o problema está acontecendo na hora que você estancia a classe `Newsletter `, você ta passando os 2 parâmetros?

Comment: Resolvi fazendo a chamada direto da Controller, ao invés de fazer por eventos e listeners.

Comment: Sim, eu estava passando os dois parâmetro e checando pelo info();